# In Dojo, why require() a module that's already been defined()?

Tags: javascript, dojo, js-amd

I'm looking at a JavaScript snippet written by another person which says,

```
define(
    [
        "dojo/a",
        "dojo/b",
        "dojo/c",
        ...,
        "dojo/z"
    ],
    function(a, b) {
        var c = require("dojo/c");
        ...;
        var z = require("dojo/z");

        // code goes here
    }
);
```

I am trying to work out why you would do this. Isn't this much shorter snippet exactly the same?:

```
define(
    [
        "dojo/a",
        "dojo/b",
        "dojo/c",
        ...,
        "dojo/z"
    ],
    function(a, b, c, ..., z) {
        // code goes here
    }
);
```

Comment: I am inclined to agree; the code doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add the require again after importing the modules once:

```
<script>require(['dojox/rpc/JsonRPC','dojo/store/Memory','dijit/form/FilteringSelect'],
        function(FilteringSelect,JsonRPC,Memory){

        ##your code goes here..

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippets are not the same in your first snippet the loader first load all the modules passed in the array to `require` and after execute the callback only when all modules listed in the array are loaded. In the callback you could run some other code before the others `require`.

Example:

```
define(
    [
        "dojo/a",
        "dojo/b",
        "dojo/c",
        ...,
        "dojo/z"
    ],
    function(a, b) {
        // execute some code here
        var c = require("dojo/c");
        var z = require("dojo/z");
        // code execute here even if c and z are not loaded yet
    }
);
```

Your second snippet the callback is executed ONLY when all modules are loaded.

Generally I would chose the second approach, even if the first approach could be handy if you need to load some modulew based on some conditions.